((FileSystemError): Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write) - Cannot save file with Cursor IDE
Problem:
Running a fresh install of Cursor IDE, from Cursor.com, a fork of VS Code, I get a FileSystemError when trying to save any file. As such, I am unable to save the python file from the IDE with Ctrl-S or File->Save.
Error detail:
Failed to save 'filename.py': Unable to write file '\Project\filename.py' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write)

Environment details:

I can save files just fine in VS Code and notepad.
This is happening in Windows 10, and will occur regardless of the file type (.txt, .md, .py, .cs, etc)
Running as administrator does not fix the issue.

Sample file:
"""filename.py"""
print("some-statement")


Solution
TLDR: You need to add the Cursor IDE to the Microsoft Defender, Controlled Folder Access allow list.

If you want to keep Controlled folder access enabled, you need to add the Cursor IDE to the allow list using the "Allow an app through Controlled folder access" option. The executable you will need to allow should be at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\cursor\Cursor.exe.
In case you are facing this issue with another vscode fork, you may get the executable path via the Windows Defender interface or with the following command:
wevtutil qe "Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational" /q:"*[System[(EventID=1123)]]" /c:10 /f:text /rd:true | Select-String -Pattern "Process Name:" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Line -replace ".*Process Name:\s*(.*)", '$1'
}

Note. This solution assumes you are using Windows and Controlled Folder Access. The error could possibly be triggered by some other system restriction. Windows may warn you with a push notification when trying to save the file.
